# Does the order of defining a jQuery prototype in my HTML file matter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following in a file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function refreshGridSetup() {

    $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
        sWrapper: 'no-margin last-child'
    });

</script>
```

Then after this I have:

```
<script src="/Scripts/admin/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Am I correct in saying that the first code is a prototype that extends dataTables?

Will it be okay to have this before the code that defines dataTables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because `$.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses` won't exist yet. You'll have to include the dataTables script first, as the jQuery prototype won't be extended until that has run.

By running your code before dataTables has created it's namespaces, you will get an error along the lines of:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oStdClasses' of undefined

**Edit**: Sorry, I didn't notice the `refreshGridSetup` function (I guess the missing closing curly brace is just a typo in the question?). If you don't call that function until *after* dataTables has been included, you won't have any problems.

Comment: Code is inside refreshGridSetup function so it depend on call of refreshGridSetup. so I believe his/her code has no problem.

Comment: @Shusl - Indeed. I edited that in - didn't notice the function wrapper at first! (By the way, from the name "Samantha" I would assume it's "her" code not "his"!)

Answer (score 1):

In the above situation it doesn't matter, because on page load, the defined function not calling. We need the prototype or function loaded when it is calling on some event.

Comment: Are you sure about this Kapildilse? James said the opposite to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
        sWrapper: 'no-margin last-child'
    });
```

above code execute when you call `refreshGridSetup` so your code is fine. but you should call `refreshGridSetup` once all resources required are loaded.

but you forgot to close body of function refreshGridSetup.
 your code should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function refreshGridSetup() {

    $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
        sWrapper: 'no-margin last-child'
    });
}// missing
</script>
```